# Update existing item

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 Application I need to work with a local SQLite database.

Since I'm not the only one doing the project, the database was created by someone else and I don't feel comfortable editing and/or searching in his code.

I need to find a way to update existing element in the database, but I do not see any way to update. I've googled through it and found a way, I'm just not sure that I'm doing it correctly (and if it will work).

**Is this a correct way to update an item in the database using linq-2-sql?**

example:

```
MyDoctorModel doctor... //existing doctor, contains properties like Name, Phone, doctorId (which is corresponding to the Id of doctor in database)
dbContext               //existing object of database, custom made, contains table object + additional methods
//I'm linq-2-sql and linq rookie, so I'm not sure if it's normal or not

//dbContext.DOCTOR is object of the table in the database, contains
//columns like Id(integer),NAME(string) etc...

var dbDoctor = dbContext.DOCTOR.Where(e => e.Id == doctor.DoctorId).First();
dbDoctor.NAME = doctor.Name;
....//etc, updating values for the actual ones

dbContext.SubmitChanges(); //and submiting changes
```

*Is this the right way to update an existing item in table?*

P.S: I know it's probably fairly easy and this is basic question, but I could not find explanation, that would be satisfactory for me (simple enough for my thick head to understand).

Comment: yes, it is the correct way, you first find the object you want to update through a context and then change some properties of it and then call `SubmitChanges` of same context

Comment: thanks. If you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is the correct way, you first find the object you want to update through your `db context` and then change some properties of it and then call `SubmitChanges` of same context